# sencha touch :: is it possible (and how) to open a website inside a panel or in external browser window?

Tags: browser, cordova, mobile-safari, sencha-touch

i wonder if and how it is possible to open a website inside a panel or in an external browser window of the mobile safari! I tried to open a website inside a panel but due to crossdomain problems only the htm without the css was loaded.

any ideas?

thnx!

edit: let's say, we use phoneGap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cross-domain issues do block you from IFRAME solutions for displaying external links inside your app.

Best solution currently is to have links include target="_blank" to force a new browser window to open.

Comment: and how does that work on mobile, i.e. iPhone? does the new window open inside my app or is mobile safari showing itself and my app shows that it isn't native? let's say we use phoneGap.

Comment: I'm not sure about PhoneGap. It may be able to do what you're looking for. And yes, the target="_blank" solution does open Mobile Safari.

Comment: @Dalar doesnt open in safari for me when using the native build in iOS or Android :(

Answer (score -1):

@Stevanicus @Dalar It does open a new window in Mobile Safari if you use Phonegap and allowed domains using phonegap.plist whitelist property, but if you do somthing like

```
var rateMsg = Ext.Msg.confirm('Title', 'Some message', function(e) {
                 if(e == 'yes')//If user confirms yes
                 {       
                    window.open("http://www.example.com", "_blank");//We open a link with _blank to use mobile safari and not your webview
                 }
              });
```

It does not work.